# no archetypes in default local catalog when creating new maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627.

When I select File -> new -> Maven Project -> Use Default Workspace Location. I get the following Dialog. Local Default Catalog is empty:

[image]

I click Configure button, and then click on [Maven Architecture Catalogs](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html). The page says:

> Location of catalog files
>
> The Archetype Plugin knows by default about its internal catalog. It
>   also knows about the local and remote catalogs.
>
> local represents the ~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog file.
>
> remote represents the
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog
>   file.
>
> The Archetype Plugin can also read catalogs from filesystem/HTTP by
>   providing the path/URL of a catalog file or of a directory containing
>   an archetype-catalog.xml file.

If Execute the following on the command line (I have everyhing under `tools` directory, Eclipse, Maven, WildFly, etc.)

```
C:\Tools>dir archetype-catalog.xml /s
```

It doesn't find any file.

So default local catalog doen't exist! Why is that?

I have downloaded http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml, but I don't know where to put it to become the default local catalog, because I don't know what `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` file path is. I tried with `C:\Tools\eclipse\.m2\archetype-catalog.xml` and several other locations without luck. Sorry, I'm new to Java eco-system and Eclipse IDE.

I have the latest M2Eclipse found here: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

EDIT: I figured out what `~` means on  `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml`. I have put `archetype-catalog.xml` into `c:\users\my.user.name\.m2\` and voilà default local catalog is now full of archetypes. But still. Why it didn't exist in the first place? This is very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The archetype catalogs used by eclipse can be found in Window -> Preferences, then in the section Maven -> Archetypes. If no catalog is listed there, you can add the official maven remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: How to configure the catalog for working in offline (no internet connection)

Answer (score 1):

No need to configure local archetypes unless you have created your own archetype. In this case, when you install it on your machine, the maven will create the **archetype-catalog.xml** file on the **~/.m2/repository** path. In another case, to retrieve any artifact the only things that you need to do is configure the remote catalog, for example, to configure Spring Catalog, you need the following

[image: Configure Spring Repository]

If you see the following screen, you can observe that I don't have anything in my Default Local Catalog similar to you while in All Catalogs, I have the archetypes from other repositories.

[image: Default Catalog Empty]

[image: All Catalogs]

Finally is important to know the difference between archetypes and dependencies. The archetypes let us create a project from it, the others are the libraries to own the project.